# Making a table from a dictionary in python

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to make a table from a python dictionary: the dictionary is generated like this:

```
for line in input_file:
  key = line.split()[0]
  value_1 = line.split()[1]
  value_2 = line.split()[2]
dic = {}
if not key in dic:
  dic[key] = value_1, value_2
else:
  dic[key] = dic[key], value_1, value_2
```

I want to make a table in the following format:

"/t" value_1 "\t" value_1
key "\t" value_2 "\t" value_2
key "\t" value_2 "\t" value_2

Here is my actual dictionary:

```
COL1A1_31 (((('RD013939-Fetal', '1392.85'), 'RD013938-Fetal', '2306.23'), 'RD013937-Fetal', '2825.40'), 'RD013936-Fetal', '3246.35')
COL1A1_32 (((('RD013939-Fetal', '5217.01'), 'RD013938-Fetal', '3914.62'), 'RD013937-Fetal', '5879.18'), 'RD013936-Fetal', '5843.70')
COL1A1_33 (((('RD013939-Fetal', '2937.83'), 'RD013938-Fetal', '2351.07'), 'RD013937-Fetal', '3439.43'), 'RD013936-Fetal', '4121.72')
```

Any ideas?

Sorry for the confusing question and my poor code... I am very new to python.

Let me provide more information. I have one text for each of several samples. The texts files that all look like this:

Target  Chr Start   End Mean_Cov    Shallow_Count   Shallow_Bases
COL2A1_38   chr12   48374677    48374771    175.6   0   none
COL1A1_30   chr17   48269320    48269405    512.76  0   none
COL1A1_36   chr17   48267341    48267489    548.89  0   none
CRTAP_7 chr3    33183866    33184060    571.77  0   none

There is a gene name (target) and then some meta data. I need to generate a summary of these text files that looks like this:

Target Mean_Cov_sample_1 Mean_Cov_sample_2
COL2A1_38 175.6 some_value_from_sample_2
COL1A1_30 512.76 some_value_from_sample_2

Does this make more sense?

Comment: That's not a dictionary...

Comment: Are you sure you didn't mean `((RD013939-Fetal', '1392.85'), ((RD013938-Fetal', 2306.23'), (('RD013937-Fetal', '2825.40'), (('RD013936-Fetal', '3246.35')))))`? At least that would be a Python representation of an a-list built on a Python representation of a linked (consed) list. Still a horribly silly thing to do in Python, but at least I'd understand what you were going for; in Lisp and other languages, a-lists are a reasonable way to store small dictionaries.

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to figure out what your input dict actually looks like, but sort that out and then modify the example below if necessary:

```
>>> d = {'key{}'.format(n): 'value{}'.format(n) for n in xrange(3)}
>>> table =  '\t'.join(['{}\t{}'.format(d.get(k), k) for k in sorted(d)])
>>> print table
value0  key0    value1  key1    value2  key2
```

Comment: Thanks for all the help. I think my question was so poorly stated that no one could figure out what I was actually asking. I hope my edits helps and thanks for your patients with a Python newbie like me!